# What is the best database transaction isolation level in this scenario?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-ec2, transactions, distributed-computing

### The scenario

I have a Node.js app that runs on AWS.

There are two EC2 instances running the same application behind an elastic load balancer. If the servers load is high, more instances could start running the same Node.js app but there is always at least 2 instances.

Both instances connect to one unique instance of postgres:

[image]

Every few seconds the ELB receives HTTP POST requests that are processed by one of the two Node.js instances. If everything goes well, each HTTP POST ends as a new row in a table, let's call it TABLE1. Each row has a boolean field named `is_processed` that allows identifying if the row has been already processed.

Each Node.js instance is also running a scheduled job that is executed every few minutes. The scheduled job searches for rows in TABLE1 where `is_processed` is `false` and processes them. If the processing logic goes well:

- Step 1: A new row is inserted or updated in TABLE2.
- Step 2: The `is_processed` column in TABLE1 is updated to `true`.

These two steps take place within a transaction.

### The problem

My problem takes place when:

- Instance A fetches some `is_processed=false` rows and starts processing then within a transaction.
- instance B fetches the same `is_processed=false` rows before A has committed its transaction.

As a result, some rows will be processed multiple times.

### Potential solution?

I believe this can be solved by using the right [level of isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html):

[image]

My problem is that **I'm not sure about the best isolation level**. My guess is that I need `REPEATABLE_READ` because there are no delete operations?

My other concern is that **I don't know if this locking could cause any kind of problems with the AWS automated DB backups**?

Comment: Choose `READ COMMITTED` and use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to lock `is_processed=false` rows from being "processed" concurrently. Or, use 
`SERIALIZABLE`, if this "processing" is taken at light-speed (i.e. trivial) and you are willing to re-try transactions.  -- `REPEATABLE READ` will actually cause you the most harm (i.e. you'll need to be prepared to re-try transactions, but won't actually solve your problem without `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`).

Comment: For your other concern: I highly doubt that any kind of locking could cause problems with automated backups. In worst case, automated backups will have to wait a few (milli)seconds more. But I'm no AWS expert though.

Comment: I will try and share here how it goes. I'm using an ORM (sequelize) I need to find out how to get it to generate a "FOR UPDATE" statement.

Comment: sequelize should [support it](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/1777).

Comment: I wouldn't take anyone's word on faith here. Best is to go the extra mile and set up a few tests to generate an artificial overload. You really would want to see what happens exactly when it bottles up. It shouldn't be too complicated. In case you are using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), it automatically supports [Configurable Transactions](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#configurable-transactions).